# How to Access Multiple Dynamic Database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

i want to access one master and multiple slave database (dynamically) in codeigniter.

connection string of all slave database are stored in master database. how to access master database in database.php file. or is there any other way to do this?

```
$db['default']['dbname_prefix'] = $dbname_prefix;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = $username_prefix.'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = $db_name;
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']= FALSE;

$db['msdb']['dbname_prefix'] = '';
$db['msdb']['hostname'] = 'should_be_come_from_first_database';
$db['msdb']['username'] = 'should_be_come_from_first_database';
$db['msdb']['password'] = 'should_be_come_from_first_database';
$db['msdb']['database'] = 'should_be_come_from_first_database';
$db['msdb']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, which one are you using?

Comment: Did you read [Codeigniter Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases)?

Comment: both, Master db runs on mysql & all other slave db runs on sql server

Answer (score 0):

What you mention `$db['default']` will be your default database. if you need to access `msdb` in code  you have to do like this

```
$db = $this->load->database('msdb', TRUE); 
$query = $db->select('*')->get('tablename');
```

Read about [Connecting to Multiple Databases - `codeigniter.com/userguide3`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases)

---

If you're manually setting DB connection you can try

```
$config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['username'] = 'myusername';
$config['password'] = 'mypassword';
$config['database'] = 'mydatabase';
$config['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$config['dbprefix'] = '';
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = '';
$config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$this->load->database($config);
```

> **Note :** you can't set values inside `database.php` from outside. You're only able to access it in your Controller/Model

Comment: This will not work. You cannot access CI objects without loading the instance in the conf file

Comment: **lol Read it.** I don't want it to load it in helper or any other. Database setting is in Controller. :P

Comment: From the original question: "how to access master database in database.php file".

Comment: So what !!! I said OP to do it in controller. and how this **`This will not work. You cannot access CI objects without loading the instance in the conf file`** will related to me ?? lol :P

Comment: read this  First **https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html#connecting-to-multiple-databases**

Comment: I missed the part where you suggested he can only do it in the controller. I dont know why the op insists on loading the db fields from the conf file `BUT IT CERTAINLY IS DOABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the credentials? Well here is a way:

create a new helper file: `Db_helper.php:`

```
function get_other_db_column_value($other_column)
{
    $ci =& get_instance(); //get the ci instance
    $ci->load->database(); // load default db;
    $ci->db->select($other_column).....//select the column value you want
    ...
}
```

In your db config:

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('Db'); //created above
$db['msdb']['hostname'] = get_other_db_column_value('hostname');
```

Comment: not working, it says 
Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on string

Comment: post an example of your a string you are passing to use in your select statement please

Answer (score 0):

```
$db['msdb']['dbname_prefix'] = '';
$db['msdb']['hostname'] = $db['default']['hostname'];
$db['msdb']['username'] = $db['default']['username'];
$db['msdb']['password'] = $db['default']['password'];
$db['msdb']['database'] = $db['default']['database'];
$db['msdb']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
```

Is that what You want?

`database.php` is normal PHP file, and `$db` is normal array, You can access right away. That's what above code do. It use `$db['default']` to define some of `$db['msdb']` properties.